# problem with scraping request list from instagram setting by selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots

I have a problem with scraping request list from instagram setting by selenium . Here is my code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

#user_info
user = 'xxx'
password = 'xxx'

#login
bot = webdriver.Firefox()
bot.get('https://instagram.com')
sleep(2)
username_input = bot.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
sleep(1)
username_input.send_keys(user)
sleep(1)
password_input = bot.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[2]/div/label/input')
sleep(1)
password_input.send_keys(password)
sleep(1)
```

bot.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/button/div').click()
sleep(3)

```
#try_to_scraping_requested_profile
bot.get('https://instagram.com/accounts/access_tool/current_follow_requests')
sleep(2)
viewmore = 0
while viewmore <4:
    bot.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/main/div/article/main/button').click()
    viewmore += 1
    sleep(1)




#this_is_where_the_problem_happend
requestlist =[]
users = bot.find_elements_by_class_name('-utLF')
print(users.text) #this_line_will_return_nothing

for user in users :
    
    requestlist.append(user.text)
#also_the_requestlist_will_be_empty
print(requestlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned

```
print(users.text) #this_line_will_return_nothing
```

`users` in your case is a `list` in `Python selenium`. You can not do `.text` on a `list`.

and for this :

```
for user in users :
   requestlist.append(user.text)
#also_the_requestlist_will_be_empty
print(requestlist)
```

I would suggest first print the size of list :-

```
print(len(users))
```

and see if it has something in it. I think it does not have anything, so try a different locator.